# Selected item position in ListView Kotlin

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, selecteditem

Im trying to load some urls on a webView depending on the item selected on a listView, this are the codes i have:

```
val animals = arrayOf("cat","dog", "mouse", "parrot", "lion", "panda")
internal lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<String>

    val list = findViewById(R.id.lista) as ListView
adapter = ArrayAdapter(
this@MainActivity,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
animals)
list.adapter = adapter
```

This is the conditional im trying to make to work

```
list.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->
        if(list.selectedItemPosition.equals(1)){
        webView.loadUrl("http://cat.com")
                }
        else if (lista.selectedItemPosition.equals(2)) {
            webView.loadUrl("http://dog.com")
        }
                }
        else if (lista.selectedItemPosition.equals(2)) {
            webView.loadUrl("http://mouse.com")
        }
                }
        else if (lista.selectedItemPosition.equals(2)) {
            webView.loadUrl("http://parrot.com")
        }
                }
        else if (lista.selectedItemPosition.equals(2)) {
            webView.loadUrl("http://lion.com")
        }
                }
        else if (lista.selectedItemPosition.equals(2)) {
            webView.loadUrl("http://panda.com")
        }
        else{
            toast("nothing")}
```

this is the button i want that make visible the layout that contains te webView:

```
        testweb.setOnClickListener {
            ListView.visibility= View.GONE
            website.visibility= View.VISIBLE
        }
```

This is how I set my ListView:

```
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lista"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/holo_orange_light" >


    </ListView>
```

All im getting so far is the toast message "nothing" xD

Thank you in advance for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->
    when(i){
        0 -> webView.loadUrl("some url")
        1 -> webView.loadUrl("some url")
        .....
    }
}
```

**INSIDE WEBVIEW**

```
 webview.apply{
    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
    settings.useWideViewPort = true
    webViewClient = MyClient()
    loadUrl("http://www.naver.com")
 }


inner class MyClient : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: 
           WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
        view?.loadUrl(request?.url?.toString())
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but when i choose an tem it opens the samsung internet explorer and displays the website, instead of only oad it inside the webView. How can i avoid that? I want it to load rhe url in my app inside the webView, not in the samsing internet explorer.

Comment: @GaboWalker it could be solved by using webviewclient. I have added content about it.

Comment: is there a way to get the same result (have the websites loaded in my webview instead of samsung internet explorer) with abother code that dosnt need to change my minskd version to 21? I kinda have my app available for older android versions and this is the only feature that doesnt allow me to. Ty